# Laravel: using WHERE CONCAT in query

Tags: mysql, laravel, concatenation

I am pretty new to laravel and facing a problem building a query using CONCAT:

```
#From input
$password = $request->password;
#sql statement
UserMainTbl::where('username', '=', $username)->whereRaw('hashkey', '=', CONCAT('admin_id'.$password))
```

Table: UserMainTbl
Field: username, hashkey, admin_id

Got error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\CONCAT()

------
*Update*:
I change my code and manage to stop the above error. But getting new error.

```
->where('hashkey', '=', DB::raw('concat(admin_id,"$password")'))
```

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password123' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_main_tbl` where `username` = xxx and `hashkey` = concat(admin_id,password123) limit 1)

------
*Update [Solve]*:
My bad on this one. It is just a simple string. Here is the solution for future reference, if any. Lol:

```
->where('hashkey', '=', DB::raw('concat(admin_id,"'.$password.'")'))
```

Can someone help to point how can I do it right?
Many thanks.

Comment: you don't have a function CONCAT. if you mean mysql CONCAT... then that CONCAT part should be included inside the single quote.

Comment: Thanks @barudo for your respond. I've update my question as per your feedback. And got another error. How can I make the password become string not as column?

Comment: you can write it as `->where('hashkey', '=', DB::raw("concat(admin_id,'$password')"))`

Comment: Thanks for your respond @jagzviruz. I tried that, it only return as **$password** instead of data inside it. I have updated the solution.

Comment: Warning:  Do NOT do it the way described in @jagzviruz's comment.  Never use a variable directly in an SQL query that way or you will likely enable injection attacks, and even something unintentional like a single quote in the $password value will cause it to fail or cause possible data loss.  Use proper parameter binding.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have solved the issue, but your solution can open up possibilities for SQL Injection if you don't escape the user input.
One way to tackle this is by adding a binding.

```
UserMainTbl::where('username', '=', $username)
  ->where('hashkey', '=',DB::raw('concat(admin_id,"?")'))
  ->addBinding($password);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Always be careful in using RAW method in query builder since it's prone to SQL injections. I suggest to separate the concatenation of the "admin_id" and "password" and use the standard WHERE method to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ronald. Do you mean use the _whereRaw_ ?

Comment: Yeah, I still using the DB::raw.

Comment: @Quzaimer: that's why I suggest on doing the concatenation on a separate variable and just use it on your where clause to avoid SQL injections. :)

Comment: Noted. Thank you for your suggestion @ronald